# itms-services IPA wireless distribution link not working

Tags: ios, ipa, software-distribution, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm trying to get an IPA downloadable through a website. From reading around I see this is done itms-services.

My issue is my link in php is not working - I have a feeling it's down to the syntax but i can't figure it out. I tried url encoding etc but no luck.

Any ideas?

```
echo '<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://localhost:8888/hockey/hockey/appname_type/info.plist">Click here to donwnload</a></br>';
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what [Apple answers themselves](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135896/is-it-normal-that-the-ad-hoc-url-doesnt-work-in-the-simulator) on this question:

> Yes, the itms:// type links don't work in the simulator.

Comment: Wow... apparently there's no real way to test them either..... TODAY WE TEST IN PROD!

Comment: Or, you know, you could have a dev/staging/qa environment :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to url encode just the url. So instead of

`http://localhost:8888/hockey/hockey/appname_type/info.plist`

you use this

`http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fhockey%2Fhockey%2Fappname_type%2Finfo.plist`

Comment: Hmm. Out of curiosity, what happens when you click the link?

Comment: Safari on my iOS simulator gives the error Cannot Open Page… Safafri could not open the page because the address is invalid

Comment: I just tried one of my links using the simulator and I get the same error you do. If you have a device available, try testing it out on that.

Comment: Tried on device - I get the error could not connect to localhost

Comment: In your info.plist file, is the value of url ```http://localhost:8888/hockey/hockey/appname_type/info.plist```

Comment: Nope my info.plist has the .ipa address

Comment: Hi - I got it working ! :-)
So you were correct with your first answer. The problem I had i.e. cannot connect to localhost was because accessing my mobile (i.e. localhost through my wifi) i had to speciift the IP address and just use the word localhost

Answer (score 2):

I "think" the URL must now be HTTPS vs HTTP, per Apple security change.

Answer (score 0):

Is your url to your ipa-file in the info.plist correct?
It needs to be the absolute url, f.e.

`<key>url</key>
<string>http://localhost:8888/hockey/hockey/appname_type/info.ipa</string>`

and it shouldn't be in a .htpasswd secured directory.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running a jailbroken iOS device that's got it's own web server, a localhost url will notwork.  I suspect your localhost reference works in Safari on your mac because it is running a web server that is serving up the files.

You'll need to specify the IP address for the Mac in your link, like

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://192.168.0.100:8888/hockey/hockey/appname_type/info.plist">Click here to donwnload</a></br>';
```

but replace 192.168.0.100 with the IP address of your Mac.

Note that this won't work in the simulator, since you cannot install apps through the itms-services