# cannot connect to example.com in iOS enterprise app

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, ios-enterprise

I'm facing a serious problem. I'm trying to make a enterprise app live.By using BetaBuilder I follows these steps:

```
myApp.ipa
manifest.plist
index.html
```

manifest.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://example.com/ios/myapp.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.com.myapp</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Myapp</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<title>Myapp - Beta Release</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <h1>iOS 4.0 Users:</h1>
  <div class="link"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/ios/manifest.plist">Tap Here to Install</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I even made the link `http` to `https`. But it always says :`Cannot connect to example.com`. Whats wrong with the setup?

Answer (score 8):

Over-The-Air iOS distributions must be served from using SSL with a verified SSL certificate.

Now to distrubute OTA you must follow these steps.

**1)** Provide a link to your generated `.plist` file that contains the manifest for the application download. This link **MUST** be served over SSL with a verified SSL certificate. An example of a valid `.plist` file is such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
        <array>
          <dict>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software-package</string>
            <key>url</key>
            <string>https://[full download url].ipa</string>
          </dict>
        </array>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
          <key>bundle-identifier</key>
          <string><full bundle identifier></string>
          <key>bundle-version</key>
          <string>[version string]</string>
          <key>kind</key>
          <string>software</string>
          <key>title</key>
          <string>[software name]</string>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

**2)**  URL key in the `.plist` file must be served from a valid SSL certificate.

Now I am not 100% of your server setup but there is the possibility the web server does not respond correctly to the `.plist` extension as well as the `.ipa` extension. You must set your web server to understand the following file extension \ mime-type:

- Extension: `.plist`
- MimeType: `application/xml`
- Extension: `.ipa`
- MimeType: `application/octet-stream`

We had many problems at first getting our applications to be deployed over the air. The biggest hurdle was around the SSL certificate and MimeTypes.

One final comment, I am sure you have your own domain and arent using example.com in your links or plist files.

Cheers..

Comment: Please tell me one thing. **This link MUST be served over SSL with a verified SSL certificate.** What do you mean by this> Can you explain further? An SSL certificate already added to the server.Kindly note that its a **nignx server.**

Comment: The SSL certificate must be from a Trusted Certifcate authority. Self signed certificates are not valid. Also see the Apple troubleshooting guides. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2319/_index.html

Comment: Ok, tell me one thing. while installing the app , will the SSL certificate be installed first or no need of certificate installation in the ios devices.

Comment: The SSL does not need to be installed into the iOS device. The certifcate  must be on the web server.

Comment: can you help me with my issue? please find it @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206022/using-azure-blob-storage-for-installing-ios-apps

Comment: Will self signed certificates still not work even after being installed on the devices?