# Using azure blob storage for installing ios apps

Tags: app-store, plist, azure-blob-storage, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

I am trying to set up a private app store using azure. I'm trying to use azure blob storage for storing .ipa and .plist files.
here is the reference:http://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/

I am able to upload files to azure blob storage and the files are available in the container with container access(i am able to browse to the file in my mobile).

Now when I try to use itms-services and open the .plist files hyperlink it is throwing that "cannot connect to xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net". But when I open the links to my ipa and plist they are working.

All the urls(html, ipa nad plist) are https only and using a mobile network so there are no network restrictions.

ex:
I am uploading the stored file as: myFile_v2-1-6.ipa, myFile_v2-1-6.plist
I am referring it in html as
https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxxxx/myFile_v2-1-6.plist">

Can someone help me with this issue? Your help will be very much appreciated.
EDIT:
my html is there in https://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 0):

Azure Blob storage was working fine.it was the problem with my plist file. 
i am editing it using XmlDocument and saving it, then XmlDocument adding braces [] to the DTD element because of which the plist file is corrupted and throwing this error.

took some to understand this and now i am removing the [] using string replace and using that plist file. app installation is all working fine.