# How do I access iOS files for OTA installation on my MS Azure WebApp?

Tags: ios, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, ipa

I could use some help on how to host my iOS and other files in the MS Azure Cloud, and access them via my MS Azure Webapp private website with OTA installations. My First go at it was not very successful.

I currently am building a web server to host the files for over-the-air installation access, and I would like to do it all inside of Azure Gov Cloud but I do not know where to host the files and make them accessable for OTA installs. I have started with a Webapp that accesses blob storage(where I store my app files and their manifests), but as iOS OTA installation requires a downloadable url link, I am having trouble with blob storage and I am thinking there may be a better solution.

So, using Azure, I am basically creating a private app store where me and my friends can upload/download apps and install them over-the-air. Unfortunately I am having issues when it comes to actually installing the .IPA file stored in blob storage.

In fact, what I was trying to do is basically the same setup as [Using azure blob storage for installing ios apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39206022/13074125).

*My current attempt/setup:*

1. I have a running web app, with a self-signed ssl cert.
2. I can access all the blob files through the web app interface, and even upload
       files to the blob containers (on any platform/device).
3. I **cannot** get the iOS download link to function and install apps
   store in the blob (or anywhere actually).

The itms-services "href" button (required for iOS installation) wont actually access the manifest, and then download the .ipa file. When I try to use itms-services and open the manifest file, the iOS device throws the error: "cannot connect to [container].blob.core.windows.net". I believe this is because it is actually cant connect to the blob storage. But then again,  I really have no clue.{see href link below}

*(items in boxes have been removed/hidden)*

```
   <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=
    https://[storage].blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net/storagecontainer/[folder]/[folder]/manifest.plist"
    >Install App</a>
```

I also tried troubleshooting the mobile device and I cannot seem to get an error out of the mobile web source code for the button for any further inspection.(let me know if anyone knows of any good tools for this)

What do you guys think I should do for storing/accessing the apps and their manifest files? Has anyone out there already done something like this that could send me some tips?
I am out of ideas at this point and open to any new ideas!

Comment: According you describe, I want to know how many files in blob, if you upload one .ipa file. And after you upload successfully,  you want to download .ipa file from azure blob by apple devices. Is am I right?

Comment: First, you can login in portal then find you .ipa asset in blob.Second check it's properties and find url. You can copy url in your code for test . And pls make sure you change access level. Check if OTA installation works. If it works, the rest will be simple.