# Enterprise distribution ios app - cannot connect to server

Tags: ios, ota, in-house-distribution, enterprise-distribution

I am trying to distribute my application from web server.

I have created .ipa file using enterprise distribution provisioning profile and certificate.

I have put .ipa file and manifest.plist file on server.

Server configuration :

We have configure IIS Manager with below mime types:

.ipa application/octet-stream

.plist text/xml

we have tried

.plist application/xml also.

My server is configured with ssl(and it is not self signed)

There is no authentication for these files.

My manifest.plist looks like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict>
<key>items</key> 
<array> 
<dict> 
<key>assets</key> 
<array> 
<dict> 
<key>kind</key> 
<string>software-package</string> 
<key>url</key> 
<string>https://www.example.com/appname.ipa</string> 
</dict> 
</array> 
<key>metadata</key> 
<dict> 
<key>bundle-identifier</key> 
<string>com.appname</string> 
<key>bundle-version</key> 
<string>1.0</string> 
<key>kind</key> 
<string>software</string> 
<key>title</key> 
<string>App Name</string> 
</dict> 
</dict> 
</array>
</dict> 
</plist>
```

now when I am clicking on below url

`itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.example.com/manifest.plist`

I am getting error like below,

`Cannot connect to www.example.com`

Can anybody help to resolve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Double-check mime types

Comment: @3000 We have check mime types many time. It's perfect as per requirement. There is some other thing that I am missing!

Comment: Have you any server log?

Comment: And have you red this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562693/ios-enterprise-deployement-clicking-on-itms-services-link-results-in-cannot-co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there was an issue with `plist` file. I was creating `.plist` file by pasting above `plist code (mentioned in the question)` in Text app in the mac and then was saving with `.plist` extension. And that might be converted to some unreadable format that my server was unable to read. For the solution, While archiving my build I have checked the checkbox **`Include manifest for over-the-air installation`** (as shown in below screenshot). and then I have provided app URL (URL for .ipa file), display image URL and full-size image URL. So, that with `ipa` my `manifest.plist` file was also generated and I have put that file without opening it and that's it!

Screenshot: 
[image]